# DocuSign iOS native signing

Tags: ios, docusignapi

With the DocuSign SDK is there any way i can implement signing experience using native UI elements and not UIWebView? just to give a better signing experience. I went through the DS rest api docs and the only way to do it is by obtaining the unique signing url and making the recipient view. I am looking for rest apis which would help me do this natively.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question is no.

But the good news is that the signing ceremony is optimized for the mobile including instructions to the signer to rotate the phone to sign. And the signing ceremony uses the mobile's locale settings to automatically provide the UI in any of [43 different languages](https://www.docusign.com/how-it-works/global).

The main issue is for you to provide 100% of the screen to the webView when the person is signing. Thanks.